# Why do i have an "Expected type specifier error"?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, nodes

I have an "Expected type specifier error at "a = new Node('A)" on the word Node in my main cpp file. Can anyone tell me why this is and possibly how to fix it? I've looked everywhere and nothing seems to solve the problem. The program is meant to make a maze of nodes A-L that the user has to navigate through.

Header File:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H
#include <string>

using namespace std;

namespace mazeGraph
{ 
    class Node
    {
    public: 
        Node();
        Node(char newNode);
        char getName() const;
        Node *getAdjacentRoom(char direction) const;
        void edge(char direction, Node *other);
        string getMovementOptions();
    private: 
        char roomName;
        Node *north, *west, *south, *east;
    };
    typedef Node *nodeptr;
}

#endif
```

Room.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Room.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

namespace mazeGraph
{
    Node::Node() : roomName(' '), north(NULL), south(NULL), east(NULL), west(NULL)
    {
    }
    Node::Node(char newNode) : roomName(newNode), north(NULL), south(NULL), east(NULL), west(NULL)
    {
    }
    char Node::getName() const
    {
        return roomName;
    }
    Node* Node::getAdjacentRoom(char direction) const
    {
        switch (direction)
        {
        case 'N':
            return north;
        case 'S':
            return south;
        case 'E':
            return east;
        case 'W':
            return west;
        }
        return NULL;
    }
    void Node::edge(char direction, Node * other)
    {
        switch (direction)
        {
        case 'N':
            north = other;
            break;
        case 'S':
            south = other;
            break;
        case 'E':
            east = other;
            break;
        case 'W':
            west = other;
            break;
        }
    }
    string Node::getMovementOptions()
    {
        string movement = "";
        if (north != NULL)
            movement = "N: North ";
        if (south != NULL)
            movement = "S: South ";
        if (east != NULL)
            movement = "E: East ";
        if (west != NULL)
            movement = "W: West ";
        return movement;
    }
}
```

Main cpp file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include "Room.h"
#include "Room.cpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    mazeGraph::nodeptr a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l;
    a = new Node('A');
    b = new Node('B');
    c = new Node('C');
    d = new Node('D');
    e = new Node('E');
    f = new Node('F');
    g = new Node('G');
    h = new Node('H');
    i = new Node('I');
    j = new Node('J');
    k = new Node('K');
    l = new Node('L');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question - it is **extremely** unusual to include one .cpp file into another one. So you should probably not do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to do `mazeGraph::Node`. The class `Node` is inside of the namespace `mazeGraph`, so the compiler doesn't know about it outside of the namespace.

```
a = new mazeGraph::Node('A');
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. And to the other guy's comment, yeah I don't know what I was doing there. Just removed it. Ha

Comment: @Justinodemon619 if that solved your issue, click the checkmark to the left of the answer. Welcome to StackOverflow :).